# Lucene doesn't search number fields

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to index and then search integer field with lucene. But it doesn't find anything (Text fields search well).

```
Document doc = new Document();    
//UserType = 1
doc.add(new IntField("userType", user.getType().getId(), Field.Store.YES));
FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(indexDir));
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

For search I tried to use next queries:

```
1) new QueryParser(defautField, new StandartAnalyzer()).parse("userType:1");
2) new QueryParser(defautField, new StandartAnalyzer()).parse("userType:[1 TO 1]");
3) new QueryParser(defautField, new StandartAnalyzer()).parse("userType:\"1\"");
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryParser` doesn't handle numerics.  You can search using [`NumericRangeQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html#newIntRange(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Integer,%20java.lang.Integer,%20boolean,%20boolean)):

```java
Query query = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("userType", 1, 1, true, true);
```